# Python remove digits in the middle of the string

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through the items in python and remove the timestamp but keep the extension

```
for item in items:
    print(item.split('_')[0])
```

Although this works but it deletes the extension as well. This how the string looks like dataset_2020-01-05.txt and this how i need it to be dataset.txt or dataset_2020-01-05.zip -> dataset.zip

I also tried this way

```
for item in items:
        print(item.split('_')[0] + item.split('.')[-1])
```

but there are some files that doesn't have timestamp and it appends .txt to those files as well, so i ended up having something like dataset.txt.txt

Comment: Have you tried to amend your code to deal with those without a timestamp?  What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove, match the date expression using the re module, and remove from the items array.

```
import re
items = ["dataset_2020-01-05.txt", "dataset_2020-01-05.zip", "dataset.txt"]
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    match = re.search(r'_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', item)
    if(match):
        items[i] = item.replace(match.group(), '')
print(items)
```

Output

```
['dataset.txt', 'dataset.zip', 'dataset.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for item in items:
        front, ext = item.split('.')
        print(front.split('_')[0] + '.' + ext)
```

or

```py
for item in items:
        ext = item.split('.')[-1]
        front = item.split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
        print(front + '.' + ext)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you have a date range, then maybe check if the date is present, and if it is present then apply the logic.

for example: if all your files contain '2020'
check

`if '2020' in items`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the RE module to help with this. For example:

```
import re

print(re.sub('[0-9_-]', '', 'dataset_2020-01-05.txt'))
```

**Output:**

```
dataset.txt
```